# Why properties `var row: Int` and `var section: Int` of `IndexPath` crash when using custom initializer?

Tags: swift, nsindexpath

It is necessary to add property `subrow: Int` to `IndexPath`. Why properties `row: Int` and `section: Int` crash?

```
import UIKit 

extension IndexPath {
    init(subrow: Int, row: Int, section: Int) {
        self.init(indexes: [section, row, subrow])
    }
    var subrow: Int {
        get { return self[2] }
        set { return self[2] = newValue }
    }
}

let ip = IndexPath(subrow: 0, row: 1, section: 2)
print(ip.subrow == 0) // OK
print(ip.row == 1) // Crash!
print(ip.section == 2) // Crash!
```

Comment: Note that the `return` statement in the setter is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The properties `row` and  `section` are defined in an extension
of `IndexPath` in the UIKit framework. They are "convenience"
accessors and meant to be used with table views or collection views.

It can be seen from the API documentation that they can only be used with index paths having 
*exactly* two elements:

```
extension IndexPath {

    /// Initialize for use with `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.
    public init(row: Int, section: Int)

    /// The section of this index path, when used with `UITableView`.
    ///
    /// - precondition: The index path must have exactly two elements.
    public var section: Int

    /// The row of this index path, when used with `UITableView`.
    ///
    /// - precondition: The index path must have exactly two elements.
    public var row: Int
}
```

See also the source code at [UIKit_FoundationExtensions.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/UIKit/UIKit_FoundationExtensions.swift.gyb).

You can use the subscript method instead:

```
let ip = IndexPath(subrow: 0, row: 1, section: 2)

print(ip[0]) // 2
print(ip[1]) // 1
print(ip[2]) // 0
```

Comment: But how to avoid this restriction?

Comment: @AlexBishop: You cannot avoid it because the precondition is built-in into the framework. You can use the subscript accessors, or define your own properties `myrow`, `mysection`